# Difference between x, y, left, right with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I have something that looks like this, which doesn't apply the x or y transform but does apply rotation.

```
$('<div/>').css(
   "-webkit-transform": "rotate(20deg)"
   x: 10
   y: 10
)
```

This applies the `x` and `y` but not the rotation:

```
$('<div/>').css(
  "-webkit-transform": "rotate(20deg)"
  x: 10
  y: 10
)
```

If I do it with `left` and `right` it works

```
$('<div/>').css(
   "-webkit-transform": "rotate(20deg)"
   left: 10
   right: 10
)
```

PS: I'm using coffeescript

Comment: None of these should work... the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: .. plus the first two examples are the same.

Comment: `left: 10, right: 10`? Do you mean `top` and `left`?

Comment: shouldn't that be `$('div').css` ?

Comment: It's like CoffeeScript syntax

Comment: im using coffeescript

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir - `$("<div/>")` means he is creating a new element.

Comment: Seems to work fine in any case, but I've never heard of these "x" and" y" styles http://jsfiddle.net/zpz8y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking why `left` and `right` work but `x` and `y` don't, it's because you're using `.css()` which is ultimately setting CSS and there is no `x` or `y` CSS properties.

You're probably looking for `translate()`:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px);
```

Comment: yeah this is the answer.  Left and right are css params.  Whereas x and y are translate params

Answer (score 0):

You can add css object as below,

```
$('<div/>').css({
   "-webkit-transform": "rotate(20deg)"
   x: 10
   y: 10
});
```

there is one jQuery plugin that do css animation.

**[`Plugin Link`](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)**

Answer (score 0):

`x`, `y` are not valid CSS attributes. You should use `left`, `top` instead.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/WNtTc/)